# how to replace delimiter value present within quotes as part of data in file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to replace delimiter which is part of data from each records. For Ex-

```
echo '"hi","how,are,you","bye"'|sed -nE 's/"([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)"/"\1;\2;\3"/gp'
```

output -->

```
"hi","how;are;you","bye"
```

So, I am able to replace delimiter(comma in this case), which is present in data also with semi colon.
But the challenge is, in real time, we are not sure how many times delmiter will be present and also, it may come in multiple fields as well.
For Ex-

```
"1","2,3,4,5","6","7,8"

"1","2,4,5","6","7,8,9"

"1","4,5","6","7,8,9.2"
```

All these are valid records.
Can anyone help me out here. how can we write a generic code to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with anything but the most trivial CSV data, I prefer to use something that understands the format directly instead of messing with regular expressions to try to handle things like quoted fields. For example (Warning: Blatant self promotion ahead!), my `tcl`-based `awk`-like utility [tawk](https://github.com/shawnw/tawk), which I wrote in part to make it easier to manipulate CSV files:

```sh
 $ tawk -csv -quoteall '
  line {
    for {set n 1} {$n <= $NF} {incr n} {
      set F($n) [string map {, \;} $F($n)]
    }
    print
  }' input.csv
"hi","how;are;you","bye"
"1","2;3;4;5","6","7;8"
"1","2;4;5","6","7;8;9"
"1","4;5","6","7;8;9.2"
```

---

Or a `perl` approach using the [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) module:

```sh
$ perl -MText::CSV_XS -e '
  my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary=>1, always_quote=>1});
  while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*STDIN)) {
    tr/,/;/ foreach @$row;
    $csv->say(\*STDOUT, $row);
  }' < input.csv
"hi","how;are;you","bye"
"1","2;3;4;5","6","7;8"
"1","2;4;5","6","7;8;9"
"1","4;5","6","7;8;9.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data does not contain embedded double quotes ...

Sample data:

```
$ cat delim.dat
"hi","how,are,you","bye"
"1","2,3,4,5","6","7,8"
"1","2,4,5","6","7,8,9"
"1","4,5","6","7,8,9.2"
```

One `awk` idea whereby we replace `,` with `;` in the even numbered fields:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" }
      { for (i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2) gsub(",",";",$i) }
1
' delim.dat
```

This generates:

```
"hi","how;are;you","bye"
"1","2;3;4;5","6","7;8"
"1","2;4;5","6","7;8;9"
"1","4;5","6","7;8;9.2"
```